# How to test a function-like Monad with cats + discipline

Tags: scala, scalacheck, scala-cats

I created a Monad-like type that is a lot like the Play Json `Reads[T]` type, called `ReadYamlValue`.

```
trait ReadYamlValue[T] {
  def read(json: YamlValue): ReadResult[T]
  // ... methods include map, flatMap, etc
}
```

I created a cat `Monad` instance for this:

```
implicit val ReadYamlValueMonad: Monad[ReadYamlValue] = new Monad[ReadYamlValue] {
  override def flatMap[A, B](fa: ReadYamlValue[A])(f: A => ReadYamlValue[B]): ReadYamlValue[B] = {
    fa flatMap f
  }
  override def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => ReadYamlValue[Either[A, B]]): ReadYamlValue[B] = {
    ReadYamlValue.read[B] { yaml =>
      @tailrec def readB(reader: ReadYamlValue[Either[A, B]]): ReadResult[B] = {
        reader.read(yaml) match {
          case Good(Left(nextA)) => readB(f(nextA))
          case Good(Right(b)) => Good(b)
          case Bad(error) => Bad(error)
        }
      }
      readB(f(a))
    }
  }
  override def pure[A](x: A): ReadYamlValue[A] = ReadYamlValue.success(x)
}
```

And then I wanted to test it with the `MonadLaws` and ScalaCheck.

```
class CatsTests extends FreeSpec with discipline.MonadTests[ReadYamlValue] {
  monad[Int, Int, Int].all.check()
}
```

But I get:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter EqFA: cats.Eq[io.gloriousfuture.yaml.ReadYamlValue[Int]]
```

How do I define `Eq` for what is effectively a function? Comparing equality of a function seems like it isn't what I want... Is my `ReadYamlValue` class not a Monad or even a Functor for that matter?

One way to do this is to generate an arbitrary sample and compare equality of the result:

```
implicit def eqReadYaml[T: Eq: FormatYamlValue: Arbitrary]: Eq[ReadYamlValue[T]] = {
  Eq.instance { (a, b) =>
    val badYaml = arbitrary[YamlValue].getOrThrow
    val goodValue = arbitrary[T].getOrThrow
    val goodYaml = Yaml.write(goodValue)
    Seq(badYaml, goodYaml).forall { yaml =>
      (a.read(yaml), b.read(yaml)) match {
        case (Good(av), Good(bv)) => Eq.eqv(av, bv)
        case (Bad(ae), Bad(be)) => Eq.eqv(ae, be)
        case _ => false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this seems like it is sidestepping the definition of equality a bit. Is there a better or more canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using Arbitrary instances is how Circe does it:

https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/blob/master/modules/testing/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/testing/EqInstances.scala

They take a stream of 16 samples and compare the results.

Comment: The only downside to this seems to be that it may be unlikely to generate a single example that both will `read` successfully. I fear that all 16 will be error results and the success case will not be tested. Does this matter much for testing the `MonadLaws`?

Comment: For the decoding side, circe really should generate some arbitrary `A` values, then encode them, and then make sure that the decoders do the same thing.